# RASPAP and Pi-Hole

Tags: wifi, pi-hole

I have RPI 3B+ with lastest version of raspbian and I have installed RASPAP (default settings) and it works very well. I have internet :) IP: 10.3.141.100/24 GW: 10.3.141.1

Today I installed Pi-Hole, during the install I choose the Wlan card and I put the IP of 10.3.141.254/24 , GW: 10.3.141.1

The Wifi does not work anymore. :( in fact the DHCP does not work anymore.

If i put a static ip to my computer, it works well but I don't have internet.
I try to activate the DHCP on the Pi-Hole Web interface. The wifi connect me by dhcp but it disconnect after 2 seconds.

I tried this:

```
pihole -r #Repair
sudo touch /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases
sudo chown pihole:pihole /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases
reboot
```

but it does not work.

Comment: I cannot find RASPAP and pi-hole in the default Raspbian repository. Where do you get it? How can I install them?

Comment: why do you want user pihole to own your dhcp lease file?

Comment: I find it. You must desactivate the DNSMASQ service before on RASPAP and put the same IP to the PI-HOLE (10.3.141.1)@Ingo