# RaspAp and Pihole

Tags: raspbian, pi-hole

Just had the same problem,like here [RASPAP and Pi-Hole](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104429/raspap-and-pi-hole) .
So I tried deactivating DNSMASQ and give the PI-HOLE the IP 10.3.141.1, same like the Raspap, but wich IP has the Gateaway?(I gave him the same: 10.3.141.1)
PiHole: 10.3.141.1 
Gateaway: 10.3.141.1 
RaspAp: 10.3.141.1 
but it does not work.

Comment: really? ip addr show all/netstat -rn|grep G

Answer (score 1):

Both projects use `dnsmasq` so integrating them is tricky. RaspAP recently added support for ad blocking, however. Details are [here](https://github.com/billz/raspap-webgui/wiki/Ad-blocking-(Beta)).

This is not meant to replace Pi-Hole on your network, but rather provide an ad blocking facility for a wireless AP.